Ranking students grades Mysqli
I have an exams table with students scores for each subject in the same table. I want to have a rank for each subject of a student. For example I want to see the student's rank in English.
The problem is that the ranking seems to be done by comparing all the student's subjects, and is therefore not giving an accurate result.
This is a snippet of the exams table:

This is the code I have tried:
$query7 =("SELECT * FROM (SELECT distinct Student_id, Subject, Total_Overal, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Total_Overal DESC) as StudentRank FROM exams) t WHERE Student_id='$gradeid' and Subject='$sub' ");
    $result7 = mysqli_query($conn,$query7);
    //echo $row['rank'];
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7))
{    //print_r(array_keys($row2));
  
    //echo $num++;
   //echo $row2['StudentRank'];
   echo "<td >"; echo $row2['StudentRank']; 

}

This the result I am getting:

i have only 40 students but the ranking is more than 40

ok so this is what worked for me. seems like i had to add more conditions $query7 =("SELECT * FROM (SELECT Student_id, Subject, Class, Academic_Year, Term, Total_Overal, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject,Class,Academic_Year,Term ORDER BY Total_Overal DESC) as StudentRank FROM exams) t WHERE Student_id='$gradeid' and Subject='$sub' and Class='$class' and Term='$term' and Academic_Year='$year'");

You need to use DENSE_RANK() instead of RANK() to get consecutive ranks without gaps.
See an explanation in MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

RANK() over_clause
Returns the rank of the current row within its partition, with gaps.
Peers are considered ties and receive the same rank. This function
does not assign consecutive ranks to peer groups if groups of size
greater than one exist; the result is noncontiguous rank numbers.

